# Show debug messages in console in bunyan

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, bunyan

```
child.log.info('info');
child.log.debug('debug');
```

I use the following command:

```
node app.js | bunyan -o short -l debug
```

However it only shows INFO. Does not show DEBUG. I'd like ot display debug messages in the console, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a logger, use the `level` option to set the level at which bunyan will emit log messages:

```
var log = bunyan.createLogger({ level: "debug" });
```

Similarly, use the `level` option to set the level at which child loggers will emit log messages:

```
var child = log.child({ level: "debug" });
```

This `level` option set at the time of instantiation determines the minimum level of log message emitted by bunyan.

The command line switch `-l` ( or `--level` ) is simply a filter; it allows through messages emitted at a given level or above. *But, it does not set the minimum level of log message emitted by your instance of bunyan.*

For example, suppose I want an instance of bunyan that emits log messages at the `"debug"` level or higher. I can put the following in `main.js`:

```
var bunyan = require("bunyan");
var log = bunyan.createLogger({ level: "debug" });

log.trace("Nitty gritty info here.");
log.debug("Eek ork op.");
log.info("The Red Zone is for loading and unloading only.");
```

If I run the following from the command line:

```
node main.js | bunyan
```

I will see this in the output:

```
Eek ork op.
The Red Zone is for loading and unloading only.
```

Notice I didn't filter anything from the command line and the call to `log.trace()` didn't print anything, either.

Now, type this into the command line:

```
node main.js | bunyan -l "debug"
```

You'll get:

```
Eek ork op.
The Red Zone is for loading and unloading only.
```

The same as before.

Now, try:

```
node main.js | bunyan -l "trace"
```

You'll still get the same output as before.

Why? Because your instance of bunyan is set to emit messages at the `"debug"` level or higher. The command-line switch `-l` is just a filter.

Finally, try:

```
node main.js | bunyan -l "info"
```

This time, you'll only see:

```
The Red Zone is for loading and unloading only.
```

The call to `log.debug()` was filtered out.

Comment: For reference on setting level in constructor: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan#constructor-api

Comment: what if you dont have access to bunyan.createLogger?  What if you only have the 'log' variable?

Comment: @johnk You'll have to figure out where your instance of `log` is getting created and adjust settings there. I highly recommend learning how to use `grep` on a code base to find where stuff is created and used in a code base.

Answer (score 0):

While creating streams for different log levels, creating a stream for debug like

```
 bunyan.createLogger({
    name: <name>,
    streams: [{
        level : 'debug',
        stream : process.stdout
    }]
});
```

Using this all your debugging logs would be streamed to the console.